# Type Script decorator error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression

Tags: typescript

i'm learning the decorator in the javascript. I use the typescrip for compile
Below is the code :

```
class Greeter {
    greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }

    @enumerable(false)
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}


function enumerable(value: boolean) {
    return 
    function(target:any,propertyKey:string,descriptor:PropertyDescriptor) {
    descriptor.enumerable = value;
    };
}
```

Actually the code is from http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html
When use tsc to compile the file , below error occurred:

**first.ts:39:5 - error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
39     @enumerable(false)**
What should I do for this issue

Answer (score 2):

Even though my tsconfig.json file included this in compilerOptions...

```
"target": "es5"
```

I still needed to state the target in the terminal's tsc comand...

```
$ tsc myFileName.ts --target ES5 -w --experimentalDecorators
```

This kept the compile error from coming up and allowed my decorator to function properly.

Answer (score 1):

You are running into a classic JS issue of automatic insertion of `;`. The single `return` on the line, will mean `return;` and will exit the function and thus the `enumerable` function has a `void` return type. Put the return function of the same line as the `return`:

```
function enumerable(value: boolean) {
    return function(target:any,propertyKey:string,descriptor:PropertyDescriptor) {
    descriptor.enumerable = value;
    };
}
```

Typescript 2.9 will highlight the unused function if your editor has support for this, and you should have an error in the decorator as well (`Identifier expected.`) since the `function` is treated as a function declaration and would have needed a name.

Comment: Thanks Titian. However, my code offline is the same to your description, and it still has the error above. Thanks for your time again!

Comment: Hi titian, I found that even is has above error, the js file that generate by the tsc can run aright. Anyway thank you for your answer and time.